# Que "highlighter" usar para Kotlin?

Tags: debate, tags, syntax-highlighting

Não existe uma opção específica para Kotlin ainda. De qual linguagem devemos usar para pelo menos ficar perto da intenção da linguagem? Java mesmo? C#? Outro?

Comment: Ué, tem isso? Eu sempre achava que era automático :p

Comment: Como se adiciona um novo highlighter? Quais usuários podem fazer isso?

Comment: É só escolher entre as opções disponíveis para moderadores.

Comment: Supostamente isso já existe: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/317050/540552

Answer (score 6):

Eu acho que deveria ser C#.

Num geral, pelo que consegui testar, o realce das duas é bem parecida, com a vantagem que em C# tem o realce de `object` com **O** minúsculo e tem **`var`**.

Kotlin usa os nomes mais parecidos com Java, como `Int` e `String`. Estes realces estão disponíveis pra C# também, uma vez que qualquer palavra em TitleCasing tem realce.

Os mais importantes que são `fun` e `val` não temos como ter.

Segue um teste

#### C#

```cs
fun teste()
Int, String, Long, object, "String", 'C', var a, val b
in, until, as, class, continue, break, for
package, super
when, while, by, delegate, dynamic, get, set, param, where
companion, const, enum, final, operator, out
public, protected, private, sealed, override
```

#### Java

```java
fun teste()
Int, String, Long, object, "String", 'C', var a, val b
in, until, as, class, continue, break, for
package, super
when, while, by, delegate, dynamic, get, set, param, where
companion, const, enum, final, operator, out
public, protected, private, sealed, override
```

#### JavaScript

```js
fun teste()
Int, String, Long, object, "String", 'C', var a, val b
in, until, as, class, continue, break, for
package, super
when, while, by, delegate, dynamic, get, set, param, where
companion, const, enum, final, operator, out
public, protected, private, sealed, override
```

Comment: Tava mesmo tentando arrumar isso.

Answer (score 4):

Coloquei Java por enquanto, vão dando o parecer. [Não ficou muito bom](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/227393/101) ([outro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/227407/101)). Mas tem [caso que ficou](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/227419/101) ([outro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/227433/101), [mais um](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/227375/101), [bem meia boca](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/224552/101)).

## Edit

Com o *link* do Victor Stafusa eu troquei para *default*, vejam se é satisfatório.

Comment: +1 default ficou ótimo.

Answer (score 0):

Mas já não existe o  `<!-- language-all: kotlin -->` ?

```
File("somefile.txt").printWriter().use { out ->
    history.forEach {
        out.println("${it.key}, ${it.value}")
    }
}
```

Comment: Existe, mas isso não *highlighta* nada, o que faz é uma configuração no site.

Comment: ahh ok, isso só ocorre no SOPt?

Comment: então acho que ´fazer funcionar ao invés de fazer uma gambis, assim quando funcionar já estará certo.

Comment: Em todos sites.